# Display data from DB in dynamically generated select box

Tags: php, jquery

I have the code that dynamically generates textboxes and select boxes upon a button click. I want to fetch the data from DB and display in the dynamically generated select box.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hEByw/11/ shows how the text and selectboxes are generated dynamically.

I have tried the following part of code to fetch the data from DB and Put into dynamically generated select box(Tax Type) but its not working for me.

```
//To Display the tax types from DB
$(function(){
    var items="";
    $.getJSON("get_tax_type.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
            items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
        });
        $("#tax_type' + counter + '").html(items); 
    });
});
```

I feel the way I am doing is wrong.Can anybody suggest where am I doing wrong or the proper way of implementing it. I am newbie in jquery. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

PHP Code(get_tax_type.php)

```
    <?php 
    include('includes/db.php');
    $q = "select TaxID, TaxName from tax";
    $sql = mysql_query($q);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
    $data[] = $row; 
    };
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. **UPDATED**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var items = "";
        $.getJSON("get_tax_type.php", function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $("#tax_type" + parseInt(index) + parseInt(1)).empty();
                $("#tax_type" + parseInt(index) + parseInt(1)).append("<option value='" + item.TaxID+ "'>" + item.TaxName+ "</option>");
            });

        }, 'json');

    });
```

Comment: Check using alert(data);. U should get [object][object]. If u didnt get anything then check ur mysql function.

Comment: I alert the data and I got [object object]. But the values are not displayed in select box. My sql query runs fine in Sql editor.

Comment: `$("#tax_type" + counter)` this is listbox or div or label?

Comment: U should use this to append value in list box. `$("#tax_type" + index ).append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</option>");`

Comment: $("#tax_type' + counter + '") is the id of the select(dropdown) box.

Comment: K check my answer and try it.

Comment: I tried that. In the select box the value "undefined" is displayed.

Comment: U have to use `item.TaxID, item.TaxName` not `item.id, item.name`. Where `TaxID and TaxName` are column names. Here i can help u but cant do all ur coding. Try small thisnga by ur self. Now check my code

Comment: No Kumar. I Can see the json encoded data returned from PHP file in firebug as [{"TaxID":"1","TaxName":"VAT"}{"TaxID":"2","TaxName":"Service Tax"}]. I am unable to figure out whats stoping the encoded data returned from php file to display under select box.

Comment: k. there should be `comma` between `{"TaxID":"1","TaxName":"VAT"}` and `{"TaxID":"2","TaxName":"Service Tax"}`.     If comma is not a problem then give `alert(item.TaxID);` in `$.each` this function. still u got problem try to create new page with one listbox and append data to it using php. dont do any other coding.

Comment: It worked now.There was a problem with javascript variable.Thanks for your help and patience Lakshmana.